# Dialogs are not getting joined on ios

Tags: objective-c, quickblox

I am using the quickblox sdk 2.3. After quickblox 2.4 sdk launch, groups are not working anymore. The code below supposed to join the groups but it isn't doing it anymore:

```
- (void)joinAllDialogs
{
    for(QBChatDialog *dialog in self.dialogs){

        if(dialog.type != QBChatDialogTypePrivate){
            [dialog setOnJoin:^() {
                NSLog(@"Dialog joined");
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationGroupDialogJoined object:nil];
            }];
            [dialog setOnJoinFailed:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Join Fail, error: %@", error);
            }];
            [dialog join];
        }
    }
}
```

This started to happen since 11-Sept-2015.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was there for 2-3 days and now its gone without any fix from code. It seems it was from Quickblox server.